# Having trouble playing sound from transferring raw PCM data to another device

Tags: python, ios, audio, streaming

I am using a [library](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) that is able to give me floating point raw PCM data.
Playing it back locally works, but I have issues being able to play it on another device.

What I am using to play audio is `PyAudio` it should be able to accept raw PCM, however, whenever I play it on another device I get bad feedback.

This is what I am doing on the python side

```
CHUNK = 512
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
WIDTH = 2

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

def audioStream_ios(payload):
    if stream.is_active():
        # print payload
        self.buffer += payload
        # stream.write(payload)
yield self.subscribe(audioStream_ios, 'com.app.audioStream_ios')

while 1:
    print len(self.buffer)
    if stream.is_active() and len(self.buffer) >= CHUNK * 1:
        data = self.buffer[:CHUNK]
        self.buffer = self.buffer[CHUNK:]
        # print 'write'
        # stream.write(data)

    yield sleep(0.01)
```

How I am getting audio on iOS side

```
Novocaine *audioManager = [Novocaine audioManager];
[audioManager setInputBlock:^(float *newAudio, UInt32 numSamples, UInt32 numChannels) {
    // Now you're getting audio from the microphone every 20 milliseconds or so. How's that for easy?
    // Audio comes in interleaved, so,
    // if numChannels = 2, newAudio[0] is channel 1, newAudio[1] is channel 2, newAudio[2] is channel 1, etc.
    // ** Send over newAudio data over network **
}];
[audioManager play];
```

I am unsure if possibly I shouldn't send over raw PCM, but maybe convert it to a continuous wav file. Or maybe there is another tool I could use to play raw PCM data.

Or even if the library I am using simply isn't a good solution for what I am trying to achieve.

I have tried converting the floating point PCM data to unsigned int values then convert to bytes but still get the same bad feedback.

Edit:

I have looked into `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCapture​Device`for trying to get live mic data but haven't been able to find good examples on how to set it up properly. Most of the time it deals with video or having to wait till the last second to get audio data.

I want something dynamic in which I get pieces of the frame at a time and send it over.

Comment: looks like your iOS device is doing the audio capture and local audio rendering is OK there ? ...  then you are trying to stream from phone to a server running your python ?  ... to confirm the audio capture to PCM is OK you can save it to a file on your phone ... download to your laptop and  playback the raw PCM audio file using audacity -> Import-> Raw Audio ... this will confirm the iOS side ... on python side you can point to a known good source of streaming PCM audio if it exists to shakedown your server side ... on your python try replacing the PCM stream by read in WAV file which is PCM

Comment: Also skip stereo for now and get mono working first (1 ch) ... on python break it down to each distinct audio sample ( your bit depth is 16 so each sample is two bytes assure your audio curve values match your iOS audio curve values )

Comment: @ScottStensland thanks for the info. I will check those suggestions out.

Comment: @ScottStensland How would I go about writing the raw PCM to file? I currently get them all in floats. Usually, sound files have bytes involved. Doing it how I am it would just be a bunch of float values. This is how I am getting the string to write to the file `NSData *textData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 1.23456789] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`